# Was the holocaust a massacre or a genocide

Tags: nouns

What is the difference between massacre and murder? Like specifically.

Comment: A *murder* might leave one person dead, and a *massacre* kills many people. But a true *genocide* kills ***all*** the people (of some identifiable ethnic or national group).

Comment: What does the dictionary say about massacre, genocide and murder?  What does, e.g., Wikipedia say about the genocide?

Comment: The title and the body ask two different questions. Please clarify and ask only one at a time. *A* holocaust has nothing to do with the difference between the definitions of massacre, murder and genocide. [*The Holocaust*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Holocaust) is a historical event when capitalized and a it has a *very* specific meaning.

Answer (score 1):

A genocide is a massacre of an ethnic or national group:

From the OED:

***The Holocaust***:

> - ***the mass murder of the Jews by the Nazis in the war of 1939–1945.*** Also used transf., of the similar fate of other groups; and attrib. The specific application was introduced by historians during the 1950s, probably as an equivalent to Heb. ḥurban and shoah ‘catastrophe’ (used in the same sense); but it had been foreshadowed by contemporary references to the Nazi atrocities as a ‘holocaust’. The term is in common use among Jews, but seems to be otherwise relatively rare except among specialists.

***Genocide:***

> - ***The deliberate and systematic extermination of an ethnic or national group.***
>
>   - ***1944*** R. Lemkin Axis Rule in Occupied Europe ix. 79 By ‘genocide’ we mean the destruction of a nation or of an ethnic group.
>   - ***1945*** Sunday Times 21 Oct. 7 The United Nations' indictment of the 24 Nazi leaders has brought a new word into the language—genocide. It occurs in Count 3, where it is stated that all the defendants ‘conducted deliberate and systematic genocide—namely, the extermination of racial and national groups. -

Comment: I've up-voted your answer, but the OED's claim that "The term is in common use among Jews, but seems to be otherwise relatively rare except among specialists," is outdated and simply untrue.

Comment: **Shoah** is the term many Jews prefer to use these days.

Answer (score 0):

**Murder** is formally an *unlawful* killing, but even in less-formal use generally refers to the deliberate killing of a person by another. When more than one person is murdered by the same perpetrator(s), "murder" generally needs to be qualified—"mass murder", for example.

**Massacre** is the deliberate killing of a large number people. It often (but not always) implies implies *indiscriminate killing*.

**Genocide** is a deliberate killing of many people *based on their ethnic or racial identity*.

**Holocaust** is destruction or slaughter on a large scale.

(**NB:** I attempted to link to the OED definitions of these, but I don't  have sufficient reputation yet to post that many links)

The actions taken by the Third Reich are aptly described as *the* Holocaust. To say "the Holocaust was a massacre" would be redundant.

The Holocaust *included* a genocide of the Jews (who were targeted mostly on ethnic, rather than religious grounds), as well as genocidal campaigns against other ethnic and racial groups. However, since [others were targeted extensively as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holocaust_victims), it would be inaccurate to say the Holocaust *was* a genocide.